# Integrate Kotlinx coroutines in intelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I‘m using intellij for a while now. There I work on a **javaFx project**, which is mainly written in java but I discovered Kotlin to be a nice alternative.

Recently I read about coroutines in Kotlin and I just can‘t figure out how to **add the Kotlinx library to my project**. I can only find the snippets for maven and gradle. But I‘m a complete nobby at this and I don‘t use one of this (At least I think so).
So how can I add the kotlinx stuff to my project???

Kotlinx:
[KotlinX coroutines](https://bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1/kotlinx.coroutines)

Project structure:
[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the Project Structure dialog, go to Project Settings | Libraries, press "+" button and select "From Maven..." in the popup. In the dialog that appears, enter the name and version of the library you need, which you can find out in the documentation. (For the [current version](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#gradle) of the core library of kotlinx.coroutines, enter `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2`). Then select the modules to which the library will be added.

Comment: very useful answer in solving this problem, especially if you're not in the android environment.

Comment: I did the above and also added the library as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#add-library-docs
Still not able to import kotlinx.coroutines

Answer (score 1):

Intellij project can you use 03 type of build systems. (gradle, maven or intellij)
In your case you use intelij as your build system.

To add external library for project that use intellij as project build system, you have to follow below steps.

There are 02 main steps to follow

**1. Define a project library**    ([doc-link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-project-library))

1. From the main menu, go to Project Structure.
2. Under Project Settings, select Libraries.
3. Click the Add button and Select "From Maven" to download a library from Maven.

   [image]

**2. Add above defined library to module dependencies**  ([doc-link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-module-library))

( *Note: Above defined libraries are not available until you add them to module dependencies.*)

1. Select "Modules" option again from Project structure window.
2. Select the module for which you want to add a library and click Dependencies.
3. Click the "Add" button and select Library.
4. In the dialog that opens, select a project or a global library that you want to add to the module.

[image]